# How to display different size images in CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

In my MFC program,I want to display different size images in a list!
I use CListCtrl and CImageList!
But the CImageList only can load fixed images!

Answer (score 1):

Variable row heights in CListCtrl is not supported.  You could take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/reportctrl.aspx) that describes a control based on CWnd that handles drawing of variable row heights.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to use the so called "owner drawn" mode to draw these myself. I don't know about another option (there is no built-in mode)... Maybe you can also take the biggest size and fit the smaller images into the bigger frames but I think it will be the same effort and be less efficient...

I mean use the
`CListCtrl::DrawItem()`
method

Answer (score 0):

Create a "grid," a non-symmetrical grid most likely, on a dialog or Form. Then populate it with irregular shaped images as you choose. If you need more space look into a Scrollable “whatever,” view, dialog, etc.

[**Irregular or non rectangular shaped bitmaps**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Non_rectangular_Picture.aspx) seems a good place to start.